# Не экспортируется класс(модуль)

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, npm

Файл модуля:

```js
import typeIs from './helpers/typeIs';

/**
 * @description Class of checking and throwing a custom exception.
 */
export default class Inspector {
// Some code
}
```

В `package.json` указал путь к файлу:

```
{
// ....
"main": "dist/app.js",
// ...
}
```

Устанавливаю пакет локально командой `npm install ../ДИРЕКТОРИЯ ПАКЕТА/`. Всё устанавливается, но консолю модуль, а там `{}`. В чём может быть проблема?

> **UPD**

Возвращает пустой объект именно в минифицированном файле(`dist/app.js`). А если подключить исходник - работает.

`.babelrc`:

```
{
  "presets": ["@babel/preset-env"],

  "env": {
    "test": {
      "plugins": ["transform-es2015-modules-commonjs"]
    }
  }
}
```

`package.json`:

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.10.5",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.10.4",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "babel-jest": "^26.1.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.1.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-commonjs": "^6.26.2",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.0",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.2",
    "eslint": "^7.5.0",
    "eslint-config-google": "^0.14.0",
    "eslint-loader": "^4.0.2",
    "jest": "^26.1.0",
    "webpack": "^4.44.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.12"
  },
  "browserslist": "> 0.25%, not dead",
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/polyfill": "^7.10.4"
  }
```

> **UPD 2**

Сам пакет: https://github.com/doox911/inspector

> **UPD 3**

Проверяю так:

```js
const Inspector = require('inspector-with-exceptions');

console.dir(Inspector);
```

Comment: что-то я так и не понял что и как ты проверяешь

Comment: @Grundy обновил

Comment: Вероятно, при минификации меняется логика. Я бы проверил исходный файл через статический анализатор со строгим набором правил, например, es-lint. И посмотрел, что он предложит.

Comment: @RomanSklyarov почему-то при минификации пропадают имена моего класса...наверно в этом проблема. Очень интересно, зачем вэбпак это делает, и можно ли это отключить?

Comment: @doox911 подобный дефект в webpack уже регистрировали: https://github.com/webpack-contrib/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin/issues/269

Comment: @RomanSklyarov Пути решения есть?

Comment: @doox911 пишут, что проблема в используемом UglifyJS. А в нем дефект еще не закрыт. Как вариант, запретить изменять некоторые имена: https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS#cli-mangle-options

Comment: @RomanSklyarov а где он из коробки установлен? Я смотрю на документации, библиотека идёт отдельным плагином.

Comment: https://webpack.js.org/plugins/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin/

Comment: попробуй это [github.com/developit/microbundle](https://github.com/developit/microbundle) - "Zero-configuration bundler for tiny modules."

Comment: Ответ на мой вопрос https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44541561/webpack-output-is-empty-object

Comment: @doox911, на свои вопросы вполне нормально отвечать самому а так же их отмечать как ответ (галочкой)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так как **Webpack** по умолчанию не подразумевает создание пакета(библиотеки), то это необходимо указать в файле конфигурации. Указывается это свойствами `output.library` и `output.libraryTarget`. Правильный файл конфигурации:

```js
const PATH = require('path');

// Автоочистка dist
const {CleanWebpackPlugin} = require('clean-webpack-plugin');

// Наименование итоговых файлов в dist
const APPLICATION_FILE_NAME = 'app';
const IS_PRODUCTION = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production';
const IS_DEVELOPMENT = !IS_PRODUCTION;

/**
 * Получить имя файла
 *
 * @param {string} exception
 * @return {string}
 */
const getFileName = exception => {
  return APPLICATION_FILE_NAME + '.' + exception;
};

/**
 * Установить loaders
 *
 * @description Влючая ESLint
 * @return {[{loader: string, options: {presets: [string]}}]}
 */
const getLoaders = () => {
  const loaders = [
    {
      loader: 'babel-loader',
      options: {
        presets: ['@babel/preset-env'],
      },
    },
  ];

  if (IS_DEVELOPMENT) {
    loaders.push('eslint-loader');
  }

  return loaders;
};

module.exports = {

  // Все исходники
  context: PATH.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),

  // Режим по умолчанию
  mode: 'development',

  // Входные точки для приложения
  entry: ['@babel/polyfill', './index.js'],
  output: {
    filename: getFileName('js'),
    path: PATH.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),

    // Имя пакета
    library: 'Inspector',
    // Параметры экспорта
    libraryTarget: 'commonjs2',
  },
  plugins: [
    new CleanWebpackPlugin,
  ],
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: getLoaders(),
      },
    ],
  },
};
```